How to sort an ArrayList not alphabetically or numerically in java
I am programming a mastermind game in java.I have an ArrayList called "checked" and as I check through the users guess, the words "black", "white" and "blank" are added to the arrayList. Is there anyway for me to sort the checked array at the end in order of importance, e.g. first "black", then "white", and then "blank"?

One simple thing you can do is to create a Map<String, Integer> and put the weight as the value and the word as the key. Custom Comparator will get the value from the map

I suggest you use an enum (which you can modify to suit your requirements). They will be sorted on their assigned ordinal value (as they appear in the enum definition). Enums are used quite often for this type of application.  Note that enums are not required to have a custom constructor.  It is only required if values are passed in the definition.
enum Colors {BLACK("Black"), WHITE("White"), BLANK("");
     private String color;
     private Colors(String color) {
         this.color = color;
     }
     public String getColor() {
         return color;
     }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Colors> colors = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Colors> colors = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            Colors.WHITE,
            Colors.WHITE,
            Colors.BLACK,
            Colors.BLACK,
            Colors.BLANK,
            Colors.BLANK
            ));
    
    Collections.shuffle(colors); // mix them up
    colors.sort(null);           // null says natural order
    colors.forEach(System.out::println);
    
 }

prints
Before sorting
BLACK
WHITE
BLANK
BLANK
BLACK
WHITE
After sorting
BLACK
BLACK
WHITE
WHITE
BLANK
BLANK


It's probably better if you strongly type your guesses as the previous answers have shown, but if you want to apply them to weak typing (I'm assuming the guesses are Strings) then this is what I meant:
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Guesses {
    final static Comparator<String> GUESS_ORDER = new Comparator<String>() {
        Map<String, Integer> ORDERS = Map.of(
                "Black", 1,
                "White", 2,
                "Blank", 3);
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return ORDERS.get(s1).compareTo(ORDERS.get(s2));
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> guesses = List.of(
                "Black",
                "Blank",
                "White",
                "Black",
                "White",
                "White");
        guesses.
            stream().
            sorted(GUESS_ORDER).
            forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}


You must store "order of importance" of the user's guess somewhere, so you can use it in your sort
I suggest using a record that will hold the key, value elements (in your case order_of_importance, color), for example :
        record Color(int orderOfImportance, String colorName) {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.valueOf(colorName);
            }
        }

        List<Color> checked = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Color(3, "blank"), new Color(1, "black"), new Color(2, "white")));

        checked.sort(Comparator.comparing(Color::orderOfImportance));
        
        System.out.println(checked); // [black, white, blank]

For more info on the record class and comparator interface :
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/language/records.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html
